# Delete diagonal elements in a 4D array

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, loops, for-loop

I have this 4D array shape `(128, 116, 116, 1)` and I want to delete the all the diagonal elements of that array, resulting in a 4D array.

I tried the following piece of code:

```
for teste in range(len(X_test)):
    X_test_LRP = X_test[teste,:,:,0][~np.eye(X_test[teste,:,:,0].shape[0],dtype=bool)].reshape(X_test[teste,:,:,0].shape[0],-1)
```

But instead of getting the same array without those diagonal elements, I get this array `X_test_LRP = (116,115)`

How can I coorect that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What language are you using, and what have you tried so far?

Comment: Hi @msbit, thanks for your reply!

I'm using Python 3.6, and I tried this for loop:         "for teste in range(len(X_test)):
            X_test_LRP[teste,:] = X_test[teste,:,:,0][~np.eye(X_test[teste,:,:,0].shape[0],dtype=bool)].reshape(X_test[teste,:,:,0].shape[0],-1)   " but I just get the result for each 1st dimension (1,2,...,128), getting a 2D array of (116,115) instead of the 4D array...

Comment: Please [edit] your question. Read [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: Thanks @lugo. Could you edit the question, adding that code so it will be properly formatted?

Comment: Sure @msbitmas I'll do it!